# IF condition and looping through an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

The method on the top should merge two String elements in an ArrayList that are side by side with each other. If the length of the ArrayList is Odd the last String element should be left unchanged.

But the problem is that is this way the program leaves the first String element alone, while the others are merged nicely. The output looks like this:

```
[1, 23, 45, 67, 89]
```

although it has to look like this:

```
[12, 34, 56, 78, 9]
```

How is it possible to fix the problem? Preferably without using the Iterator.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<String> clump (ArrayList<String> list)
    {
for (int i =0; i< list.size(); i++)
//for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
{
   // if (i == 0)

   if ((list.size() + i) % 2 == 0) {
       System.out.println(list);
       System.out.println("list size is " + list.size());

        String newElement = list.get(i) + list.get(i+ 1);
        list.remove(i);
        list.remove(i);

        list.add(i, newElement);
       //System.out.println(list);
   }
   else {
       continue;
   }

}
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");

        System.out.println(clump(list));

    }
}
```

Comment: It might have to do with the fact you are referencing `list.size()` which is dynamic to the list. Since you are removing items, you are changing the size and thus changing the condition of your for loop.

Comment: If you are removing things from a list as you iterate, you should almost always be iterating from last to first. This usually prevents skipping elements in the array.

Comment: Can you please accept answers from your previous posts? Or comment on them if they don't solve your problems? You **shouldn't** do `list.remove()` using a forward-loop, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)`

Comment: @Edga - please accept an answer if any of them have helped you resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine if the input `list` has even number of elements. For the case when you have odd number of elements in the list, remove the last element from the list and save it temporarily before running your code. Add the last element back to the output returned.

This can be one solution (may not be the best solution):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<String> clump (ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        // BEGIN CHANGES MADE
        String temp = null; 
        int size = list.size();
        if ((size%2) != 0)
        {
            temp = list.remove(size-1);
        }
        // END CHANGES MADE
        for (int i =0; i< list.size(); i++)
        {
           if ((list.size() + i) % 2 == 0) {
               System.out.println(list);
               System.out.println("list size is " + list.size());

                String newElement = list.get(i) + list.get(i+ 1);
                list.remove(i);
                list.remove(i);

                list.add(i, newElement);
               //System.out.println(list);
           }
           else {
               continue;
           }

        }
        // BEGIN CHANGES MADE
        if (temp != null)
        {
            list.add(temp);
        }
        // END CHANGES MADE
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");
        //list.add("0");
        System.out.println(clump(list));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to check `if ((list.size() + i) % 2 == 0)`. On every iteration you can concatenate adjacent elements.

Also, you will need to loop until `i < list.size()-1` instead of `i < list.size()` because when you remove the 2nd last element, you are already at the last index.

So remove the `if-else` block `if ((list.size() + i) % 2 == 0)`.

and replace:

```
for (int i =0; i< list.size(); i++)
```

with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
```

Here is a working version of your program:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class So {
    public static ArrayList<String> clump(ArrayList<String> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size() - 1; i++)
        // for (int i = list.size()-1; i >=0; i--)
        {
            // if (i == 0)

            System.out.println(list);
            System.out.println("list size is " + list.size());

            String newElement = list.get(i) + list.get(i + 1);
            list.remove(i);
            list.remove(i);

            list.add(i, newElement);
            // System.out.println(list);

        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");

        System.out.println(clump(list));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope it helps you out. I used your code. It was enough good idea. Some change helped on it to work fine. Try it out! :D

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static ArrayList<String> clump (ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        int halfSize = list.size()/2;
        for (int i =0; i < halfSize; i++) {
             System.out.println(list);
             String newElement = list.get(i) + list.get(i+1);
             list.remove(i);
             list.remove(i);
             list.add(i, newElement);
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("1");
        list.add("2");
        list.add("3");
        list.add("4");
        list.add("5");
        list.add("6");
        list.add("7");
        list.add("8");
        list.add("9");
        list.add("10");
        list.add("11");
        list.add("12");
        list.add("13");
        System.out.println(clump(list));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static ArrayList<String> clump(ArrayList<String> list) {
    ArrayList<String> res = new ArrayList<String>();
    Iterator<String> itr = list.iterator();
    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        res.add(itr.next() + (itr.hasNext() ? itr.next() : ""));
    }
    return res;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ArrayList<Integer> getMinCoins = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // function to receive change in the form of coins
    {
        
        for (int i: coins){
            getMinCoins.add(i);
            System.out.println(getMinCoins);
         
            }
        }
```